# Embed image in flex? Export -> release build not working.

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, release

I've a flex application which has actionscript file, images. When i run this in adobe flash builder, everything works. When i export it as a release build and run in other file, swf does not show images and interactivity of flex components is also lost.

Is there a specific way to embed images?

Here is image code,

Comment: How are you running it in the other file?

Comment: I'm outputting the release build to desktop file and running.

Comment: That doesn't sound like you're actually putting it inside another movie. Can you provide more details about how you're using it _inside the other file_?

Comment: The other file means i'm creating a new folder in desktop like "ProjectBox" and then exporting it. 
I corrected the error and now its working, the image i declared was not yet Bindable and not a class. I changed it to bindable and now it works. 
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see your code, but I've had similar issues before. The trick is to reference the image starting with a forward slash '/' in the path. For example, if the image is located at 'img/test.png' then use '/img/test.png' as the embed source path. You should also check to make sure the image is included in your build path.

Comment: Now i can see the image in the output release build. But the effects are not working on the image. If i just delete the image and then run  the swf, i can see effects.
So the image is causing the problem after export build-release. How to insert image in a proper way to prevent this?

Right now i've a folder called img, inside i've some images.

Comment: I don't think I can answer this second part without seeing your code. Can you edit your post to add it? (forgive me if it's already there, but Firefox 5 doesn't seem to be rendering it)

Comment: I solved the error, it was image error, 
[Bindable]
   [Embed("../img/Human_eyesight_two_children_and_ball_normal_vision.jpg")]
   private var image1:Class;
   
Yea firefox 5 seems to have bugs, need to go back to chrome!